# any way to read DATA/ directory's CONTACTS.DB?

Tags: data-recovery

Suddenly my HUAWEI (Android  4.2.2) bricked. It stucks at BOOT LOGO.
However,when i connect to USB, ADB is able to read phone memory (`shell` and `ls`), But the `/data` directory is not readable (permision denied)

I need contacts (people say it is located in `/data/com.android.providers.contacts`, but ia m not sure).
What to do? i had no backup of contacts, I cant loose them, they are important? 
WHat's solution ? How to get custom ADBD to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you read is about correct: contact is stored in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db`.

You will only be able to read `/data` if you're rooted. Although Android 4.2.2 should be easily rootable by now, the fact that you're stuck in the boot logo (likely a bootloop) means you can't keep a stable ADB connection, therefore no rooting tools would work (requires stable connection for minutes).

Comment: It loads ADB well and connection seems stable while USB (just phone is not going to DESKTOP), otherwise connection and directory listing works well.