# How to install SuperSU using adb while the phone is in TWRP recovery with a broken screen

Tags: adb, root-access, twrp, authorization

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 SHV-E330S with a broken screen (cannot see or touch anything). [Please see this and it's comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217563/which-file-has-the-saved-contact-data-in-android-how-to-get-this-file-in-an-unr) for more context

I have managed to flash TWRP on this phone (https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxys4ltea.html) and now I can boot the phone into recovery mode and during this time I can use adb to get a root shell on the phone

I would like to find a way to stream it's screen to the laptop monitor and control it using adb, but I suppose I will need to root the android OS first to this more easily

I cannot use the phone screen so I am not sure how I can install SuperSu.apk from the phone itself. Is there a way to install it through adb? I think the adb shell I get while the phone is in recovery is not the android OS if I understand it correctly, so I don't know adb pm install while in recovery will install the apk correctly. Using adb to control the phone while in recovery is the only I can do anything at all with this phone at the moment so as far as possible I don't want to do anything wrong which might make me loose control of adb during recovery. What is the best way to go about this?

Or is there any way to get adb authorization for android OS, without root and completely through adb while in recovery?

Comment: See if my answer helps you in bypassing adb authorisation issue. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120453/96277 // As for rooting the device you need to flash a SuperSU zip. It would install all the necessary files including the SuperSU apk. However,  it is best you find solution for adb authorisation and streaming display to external sources because SuperSU needs to be configured too and you can't as of now due to non-functional screen.

Comment: @Firelord I'll have a look at the authorisation issue using your answer thanks. If this part is solved, then for at least streaming the display and controlling the phone through adb, I can do it without having root? And even if I am able to view the android OS screen on PC and control it through adb, will it make it any easier to root in later on? because I am guessing I can't stream the screen contents while in recovery, and I thought that was the point where I have to do the rooting process

Comment: I don't think there are much choices to stream screen content for Kitkat devices without root access, but you are free to search into. You have the twrp access which actually is the easiest thing to root a device. My suggestion is  that you prioritize adb access first, than find solution to stream, and if all good solutions need root access than only root your device.

Comment: @Firelord I found the adbkey.pub file in my .android folder and pushed it to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` like it says in your answer while the phone was in recovery mode. I rebooted the phone and I still get unauthorized when I type `adb devices`. trying to `adb shell` into the phone while it it running android OS  (not in recovery) I get this error: `error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.` Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @Firelord the other rooted phone does not have an `adb_keys` folder inside ` /data/misc/adb/` and to be honest I don't exactly remember if I ever authorised this phone on my PC or not, I think it has always "just worked" after I connected the USB cable. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @Firelord with the adbkey.pub still in place, I added the lines mentioned in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507415/1693203) and the phone is still unauthorised

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to recommend now. :(

Comment: @Firelord it's working now https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218640/how-do-i-bypass-the-rsa-authentication-dialog-box-to-enable-controlling-phone-fr