# How can I long press on android screen projected on PC using adbcontrol?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, touchscreen, broken-screen

I am using adbcontrol (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/168907/37436) to stream and control android screen of a cracked android phone. It looks like this method is pretty slow and does not detect long presses. Is there any way to make this program detect long press on the projected screen, and to make to run any faster? I have set screenshotDelay = 100 in the config.properties file.

Alternatively, is the MyScreenExplorer (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42131/37436) app any better? I wasn't able to install this app on this phone before and couldn't figure out what the problem was so I gave up. But if this app is noticeably better (faster response, has log press support, etc) then I will try to install it once again. If there are samsung specific tools that work better, I would like to know about them a well. The phone is an unrooted [Samsung Galaxy S4 SHV-E330S](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218626/how-to-install-supersu-using-adb-while-the-phone-is-in-twrp-recovery-with-a-brok) with Android 4.x (not sure of the exact version, most likely 4.4)

Comment: @Robert I think scrcpy needs Android 5.0 and above

Comment: try other solutions from your link

Comment: @alecxs I know I'm just trying to figure out which of the other tools are worth giving more time.

Comment: Vysor is fluid, but I never got WebGL enabled in windows chrome browser, so ended up with scrcpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use adb to send a longpress key event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142843/how-can-i-use-adb-to-send-a-longpress-key-event)

Comment: @alecxs I was hoping I could do everything from a single app, instead of just doing long presses from a separate adb instance

Comment: @alecxs I ended up using MyScreenExplorer. It's not very fast either but still pretty usable

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure I used adbcontrol to unlock pattern. This mean adbcontrol is capable of swipe, and therefore of long press touch input too. Either something is interrupting touch input (ghost touches) or you are just impatient (because of the haltingly frame sequence)?

Make touch events visible in developer options. Try again very very slow