# How do I bypass the RSA authentication dialog box to enable controlling phone from adb?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, authentication

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S4 SHV-E330S with a broken screen (cannot see or touch anything)

For more context please see my old questions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217563/which-file-has-the-saved-contact-data-in-android-how-to-get-this-file-in-an-unr?noredirect=1#comment281787_217563) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218626/how-to-install-supersu-using-adb-while-the-phone-is-in-twrp-recovery-with-a-brok?noredirect=1#comment281793_218626).

I have already tried these:

[Can I enable USB debugging using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120394/can-i-enable-usb-debugging-using-adb/120453#120453)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device

Nothing seems to work. I have pushed the adbkey.pub file in .android folder in the PC to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` in the phone while in recovery. On rebooting to android it was still unauthorized. I am pretty sure that before the screen c\broke AI had developer mode and USB debugging enabled on this phone. regardless, I executed the commands shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507415/1693203)

```
adb shell mount /system
abd shell

echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> default.prop 
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> default.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> default.prop
echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> /system/build.prop 
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> /system/build.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> /system/build.prop
```

since I found out that the above lines of text were not in the original `default.prop` and `/system/build.prop` (even though I am pretty sure I had enabled USB debugging before the screen broke). Even after adding these lines, the phone is still unauthorized when I reboot to android. Since then I have recovered the original `default.prop` and `/system/build.prop` into the phone.

What else can I try now to bypass the RSA authentication dialog box? I have another rooted android phone (different model and OS version) which I have full access to through adb, but it does not even have an `adb_keys` folder inside `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`, so I can't just copy over from that phone to this phone either.

What else can I do to bypass the RSA authentication dialog box on this phone?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using clues from [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/solved-adb-unauthorized-rsa-prompt-t3693961)

> If you only need to authorize one computer:
>    Simply copy the adbkey.pub
>   onto the device location:
>     /data/misc/adb/ and rename it from
>   adbkey.pub to adb_keys
>    chmod 0644 and then reboot.

I forgot to do the chmod but still works.

Comment: So you **passed** the RSA Authentication this way, not **bypassed**.

Comment: more safe method is *'adb push adbkey.pub /data/local/tmp; adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/adbkey.pub >> /data/misc/adb/adb_keys'* that won't erase existing RSA keys or change file permissions

Comment: The question is how to bypass this prompt for all devices. Just connect without authorization at all.